# DataFrame GroupBy multi level selection

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to use pandas to solve problem that I've done with pure python, but don't know the best practices for DataFrame groupby.

I want to for each post code to select what is the percentage (of all drugs in that post code) of the most prescribed drug.
If two drugs have the same quantity prescribed I want to pick up the one that is "first alphabetically":

```
import pandas as pd

drugs_prescriptions = pd.DataFrame({'PostCode': ['P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P2', 'P2', 'P3'],
                    'Drug': ['D1', 'D2', 'D1', 'D2', 'D1', 'D2'],
                    'Quantity': [3, 6, 5, 7, 7, 8]})

    Drug    PostCode    Quantity
# 0 D1      P1          3
# 1 D2      P1          6
# 2 D1      P1          5
# 3 D2      P2          7
# 4 D1      P2          7
# 5 D2      P3          8

#This should be the RESULT:
# postCode, drug with highest quantity, percentage of all drugs per post code
# (post code P2 has two drugs with the same quantity, alphabetically first one is selected
# [('P1', 'D1', 0.57),
# ('P2', 'D1', 0.50),
# ('P3', 'D2', 1)]
```

I've done grouping by postCode, drug but have issue selecting rows (apply lambda).

```
durg_qualtity_per_post_code = drugs_prescriptions.groupby(['PostCode', 'Drug']).agg('sum')
```

[image]

all drugs sold per post code, I intend to use this one with apply or transform one the previous data set:

```
all_by_post_code = drugs_prescriptions.groupby(['PostCode'])['Quantity'].sum()
```

[image]

I am not sure how to select row with drug max Quantity per post code, in the case two drugs have same quantity the one with first alphabetical order should be selected (D1 for post code P2).

I've wanted to do something like this:

```
durg_qualtity_per_post_code [durg_qualtity_per_post_code .apply(lambda x: int(x['Quantity']) == max_items_by_post_code[x['post_code']], axis=1, reduce=True)]
```

UPDATE:

```
# sort by PostCode, Drug
df = drugs_prescriptions.groupby(['PostCode', 'Drug']).agg('sum')
df = df.groupby(['PostCode']).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['Quantity', 'Drug'], ascending=[False, True]))

# select first value by PostCode
# reset index in order to have drug in the output as well
df.reset_index(level=[1], inplace=True)
df = df.groupby(['PostCode']).first()

# calculate percentage of total by PostCode
allQuantities = drugs_prescriptions.groupby(['PostCode']).agg('sum')
df['Quantity'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Quantity']/allQuantities.loc[row.name], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible solution, but it feels awkward and un-pythonic. But it works, comments are in the code.

```
# setting string to integer
df.Quantity = df.Quantity.astype('int')

# create a mulitiindex
df.set_index(['PostCode', 'Drug'], inplace=True)

# use transform to divide the sum of the 'Drug' level by the 'PostCode' level
df = df.groupby(level=[0,1]).transform('sum') / df.groupby(level=0).transform('sum')

# move 'Drug' out of the multi index to allow for sorting
df.reset_index(level=[1], inplace=True)

# Sort the 'Quantity' descending order, and the 'Drug' in ascending order,
# then we can select the first 'PostCode' for our result
df.sort_values(['Quantity','Drug'], ascending=[False, True], inplace=True)

df.groupby('PostCode').first()

           Drug Quantity
PostCode        
P1          D1  0.571429
P2          D1  0.500000
P3          D2  1.000000
```

Comment: Thanks, lot of material to look into. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @user007 It was a good question, I learned a couple of things myself. Thanks.